# Two phone numbers on FaceTime

Tags: iphone, ipad, apple-id, facetime

We have 2 iPads, 2 iPhones and 1 Apple ID. How can I add the 2nd iPhone number? Would like to have *my* iPad FaceTime & messages associated with *my* iPhone; my husband's iPad FaceTime & messages associated with his iPad.

Comment: How many AppleID's are you using?

Answer (score 2):

1 Apple ID is the problem.

You'd need to remove the ID as a contact source & just use the phone numbers.
Settings > Facetime

[image]

<sub>Same settings for iPad, just laid out slightly differently</sub>